# Creating symlink for a git repo that is used as a package

Tags: linux, git, npm

In a translation project that I use there's the need to use a file to control some settings, and to respect the folder structure of the project, we need to replicate this on each language folder.
The folders are  `en`, `pt`, `es`  each one of them needs to have `controls` inside of them, and with this problem I had the idea of creating symlinks, but whenever I push them the relative path from each file seems to be resolved to an absolute path, so when using this as a package this is not going to work well.

When creating the symlinks, I used: `ln -rs src/controls.json src/locales/*/` replacing the `*` for each folder mentioned above.
When running the `symlinks` util on my repo, it shows the correct paths:

```bash
symlinks -rv . | grep controls

relative: $HOME/resources/src/locales/es/controls.json -> ../../controls.json
relative: $HOME/resources/src/locales/en/controls.json -> ../../controls.json
relative: $HOME/resources/src/locales/pt/controls.json -> ../../controls.json
```

But when I push this and go to my main project, where this repo is being used as a package on my `package.json`  all the symlinks are `dangling` because their relative path are now absolute, pointing to `src/controls.json`.

```
symlinks -rv node_modules/resources | grep controls 

dangling: $HOME/project/node_modules/resources/src/locales/es/controls.json -> src/controls.json
dangling: $HOME/project/node_modules/resources/src/locales/en/controls.json -> src/controls.json
dangling: $HOME/project/node_modules/resources/src/locales/pt/controls.json -> src/controls.json
```

Is there a way of keeping this relative path? Or maybe a better solution to this?
Thanks

P.S. `$HOME` is just my redacted home path, so it's showing it an absolute path, and I'm using i18n backend plugin with this folder structure.

Comment: You cannot store a symlink in a git repository that points outside of the repository (that could lead to surprising and possibly dangerous behavior). Maybe you need a wrapper script to run things that takes care of setting up the necessary filesystem structure?

Comment: I tried a lot of things, but in the end I just made a “script” that I had to run every time I needed to change those files. Even though it's not the one I was looking for, it's the one that looks the most promising. Better than needing to update all of them every time, at least.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, what did you mean 'wrapper script'? Was it a similar solution to what I did, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

When I do this it works.

```
git init deleteme; cd $_
echo test >data
mkdir tdir
ln -rs data tdir/link
(cd ..; ln -rs resources/data deleteme/tdir/extlink) # `resources` doesn't exist
(cd ..; ln -rs deleteme/data deleteme/tdir/outninlink)
git add .; git commit -m-
git clone . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
ls -l tdir
```

and pasting that into my terminal gets

```
$ git init deleteme; cd $_
echo test >data
mkdir tdir
ln -rs data tdir/link
(cd ..; ln -rs resources/data deleteme/tdir/extlink) # `resources` doesn't exist
(cd ..; ln -rs deleteme/data deleteme/tdir/outninlink)
git add .; git commit -m-
git clone . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
ls -l tdir
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jthill/sandbox/deleteme/.git/
/home/jthill/sandbox/deleteme
[master (root-commit) 9ac68f0] -
 4 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 data
 create mode 120000 tdir/extlink
 create mode 120000 tdir/link
 create mode 120000 tdir/outninlink
Cloning into '/tmp/jthill/tmp.6j8cc1W7kT'...
done.
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jthill jthill 20 Jun 23 18:38 extlink -> ../../resources/data
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jthill jthill  7 Jun 23 18:38 link -> ../data
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jthill jthill  7 Jun 23 18:38 outninlink -> ../data
```

and likewise with pushing to a freshly init'd bare clone and then cloning from that.

So I'm not sure what your system's doing. I'm on 2.41+, what version of Git are you using?

Comment: I can't say for sure, since it's on my work laptop, but I always keep everything up to date, so I would guess I'm at 2.41 (LTS) too.
If you pushed this project that you created, and tried to use it in a package.json as a dependency, would the links keep being relative, like you showed in the last line? Because that was my problem. The path was resolved to an absolute path after pushing and installing it as a dependency.
I'll try that tomorrow morning too, rn it's already pretty late.

Comment: I see. I don't speak npm and have no idea what that "symlinks" command is or why you wouldn't just use `find -type l`.  Push and checkout literally cannot change what was committed, the inviolability of content is Git's strongest (literally "because math") guarantee so it's either your installer or that command.

Comment: That's probably right, I think when the project is downloaded it may convert the file symlink, which is probably why its causing problems. And the `symlinks` is just another way of finding symlinks recursively.